# Apache Ant - program output accompanied by "[java]" tags

Tags: java, ant

A stupid question, but I couldn't find an answer anywhere.

Currently learning Apache Ant and I started by making a very basic build file and java project that prints a line of string to the console. This is what is outputted when I used the command

`ant compile jar run`

```
PS C:\Users\zayd\Desktop\Apps\pbox> ant compile jar run
Buildfile: C:\Users\zayd\Desktop\Apps\pbox\build.xml

compile:
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Users\zayd\Desktop\Apps\pbox\build\classes
    [javac] C:\Users\zayd\Desktop\Apps\pbox\build.xml:9: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.s
ysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
    [javac] Compiling 8 source files to C:\Users\zayd\Desktop\Apps\pbox\build\classes

jar:
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Users\zayd\Desktop\Apps\pbox\build\jar
    [jar] Building jar: C:\Users\zayd\Desktop\Apps\pbox\build\jar\Main.jar

run:
    [java] ~We'll go down in history~

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 1 second
```

Is there a way to remove the '[java]' tags that are being printed alongside the program output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, no you can't. The task prefix in the output is controlled by Ant's logging mechanism, not by the `java` task itself so there is no way to change the `java` task usage to remove this output.

The only way is to write your own `BuildLogger` to customize the build event messages, then instruct Ant to use this custom logger instead of the `DefaultLogger` which Ant uses by default. See https://ant.apache.org/manual/listeners.html (the link includes a pointer to writing your own listeners and loggers).

If you really intend to do that and not just asking this for curiosity, then here's a snippet taken from `DefaultLogger` which pinpoints how a build event message is logged with the task name:

```
/**
 * Logs a message, if the priority is suitable.
 * In non-emacs mode, task level messages are prefixed by the
 * task name which is right-justified.
 *
 * @param event A BuildEvent containing message information.
 *              Must not be <code>null</code>.
 */
public void messageLogged(BuildEvent event) {
    int priority = event.getPriority();
    // Filter out messages based on priority
    if (priority <= msgOutputLevel) {

        StringBuffer message = new StringBuffer();
        if (event.getTask() != null && !emacsMode) {
            // Print out the name of the task if we're in one
            String name = event.getTask().getTaskName();
            String label = "[" + name + "] ";
```

Answer (score 4):

Did you try the `-emacs` command-line option?

https://ant.apache.org/manual/running.html